# Evaluating a decimal exponent

Tags: radicals, wolfram-alpha, calculator

The example I am stuck with is $(-1)^.456$. According to my calculator, the answer is -1. According to WolframAlpha and the Google Calculator, it is a complex number.

WolframAlpha -- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5E.456

The way I see it, you first rewrite .456 as a fraction, which is $57/125$ in simplest form. If you were to evaluate this it would be $\sqrt[125]{(-1)^{57}}$. Based on this logic, since both the exponent and radical are odd, the result should be -1. However, more confusion comes in when I try to use .456 as a fraction not in simplest form (e.g. $114/250$). I get $\sqrt[250]{(-1)^{114}}$ and since both the radical and exponent are even, the result should be 1. Moreover, if I evaluate it alternatively like $(\sqrt[250]{-1})^{114}$, then I get a complex number.

Can anyone shed any light on this issue?

Comment: The simple answer is that negative numbers to a non-integer power is a messy business, and should be avoided as best you can.

Comment: [Here](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/04/26/get-real-with-wolframalpha-computing-roots/) is a WolframAlpha blog post that describes a bit about how non-integer roots are dealt with by WolframAlpha. The post deals with rational roots which is related but a bit different from decimal roots, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that $\sqrt[250]{(-1)^{114}}$ seems to only be $1$ is that you're forgetting something: $\sqrt[n]{1}$ is always really $\pm1$, meaning that $-1$ is also a valid solution.

The reason that $(\sqrt[250]{-1})^{114}$ gives you a complex number is that the calculator is following the order of operations and finding the $250$-root of $-1$ (which is $i$) before taking that result to the $114$ power - although that should lead you to $-1$, not some multiple of $i$.

Arthur's advice, though, is the best anyone can give you:

> The simple answer is that negative numbers to a non-integer power is a messy business, and should be avoided as best you can.

Comment: I see your reasoning on the first cause (multiple solutions) but these solutions are not the same as the other cases which is still an issue. Also I see your reasoning, on the second case, where it should be -1, not a complex number. That leaves the question of why this occurs then: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5E.456. And in the last case it should evaluate to -1 although I don't see how it will lead to the "same problem" as in that case i is never involved. Finally, if all this is true, we are getting multiple answers, so what is the conventional method for evaluation?

Comment: For the last case: $(-1)^{57}=(-1)^{56}(-1)=-1$, so this becomes $\sqrt[125]{-1}$, which should involve $i$. As for the conventional method - I don't know what most people use. For me, it would depend on the context of the question.

Comment: But isn't the 125th root of -1 simply -1 without involving i since it is an odd root?

Comment: Oh, I think I made a mistake there by improperly using $125$. Yes, you're right.

Comment: Actually according to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cube+root+of+-1, there are multiple third roots for -1, including ones that involve i.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't considered using $e$. I was trying to find a pure number, though, as opposed to an expression.